# Apply a function into grouped dataframe using Scala Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to do DBSCAN in each group of latitudes and longitudes from users. The implementation of this clustering algorithm was done by irvingc [here](https://github.com/irvingc/dbscan-on-spark). I bumped up all dependencies to make the code work properly in my env.

Describing the sistuation: I have a Dataframe which is composed by events from user, each event has an id, a lat, and a long, you can see the columns by this case class. By that, I transform the dataframe to dataset to use the groupbykey and mapgroups methods to apply the function to the grouped data. However, the DBSCAN I'm using receive an `RDD[linalg.Vector]`, so I have to transform the group into Vector of lat/lon, and this transformation gives the error SPARK-28702. Can you give some advice how to handle this issue?

```
case class StayDataset(objectID: Long, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, timeStart: Long, timeEnd: Long)


var dfs: Array[DataFrame] = Array()
val s = dataset.groupByKey(k => k.objectID).mapGroups{
  case(k, iter) => {
    POIDetection.groupStayPointsFromUser(k, iter, dataset.sparkSession)

    dfs = dfs ++ Array(df)
    k
  }
}

def groupStayPointsFromUser(k: Long, dataset: Iterator[StayDataset], spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
  val points = dataset.map(row => Vectors.dense(Array(row.latitude, row.longitude))).toSeq


  val rddVector = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(points)
  val size = points.length

  val model = DBSCAN.train(rddVector, eps = 20, minPoints = (size * 0.18).toInt, maxPointsPerPartition = (size / 4).toInt)
  val pointRDD = new PointRDD(model.labeledPoints.map(p => {
    val point = POIDetection.geoFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(p.x, p.y))
    point.setUserData(p.cluster.toString())
    point
  }))

  val df = Adapter.toDf(pointRDD, Seq("cluster"), spark)
    .select(col("cluster").cast("long"), col("geometry"))

  df
}
```

I think this problem arises when we want to apply a KNN in a grouped data. How to do that?

Comment: you are passing sparksession to the function parameter of mapGroups. sparkSession cannot be serialized and sent to executors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to achieve but first, you need to create a RDD[linalg.Vector], I suppose that you have the dataset of StayDataset already, to retrieve the RDDs, you need to transform the Dataset of StayDataset to linalg.Vector

```
val dsVector = dataset.transform[linalg.Vector](rec => linalg.Vectors.dense(rec.latitude, rec.longitude))
```

and then you retrieve the rdd[linalg.Vector]:

```
val rdd = dsVector.rdd
```

and you pass the rdd to your DBSCAN:

```
DBSCAN.train(rdd, ...)
```

These are necessary for your to get the rdd to do the train.
I think you also need to do some aggregation beforehand. If it is true, you need to manipulate on the dataset you have

Comment: I would like to train DBSCAN for each user (objectID) I have on Dataset. So, I have to do the aggregation, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @GermanoBarcelos Are you aware of all the objectId you have in your dataset? if you don't you will need to do: val ls = dataset.select("objectId").distinct().collect() to retrieve the list of your ids. and then you iterate the ids in your list to filter out datasets of different id: ls.map(id =>DBSCAN.train( dataset.filter($"projectId"=== id).as[StayDataset].transform[linalg.Vector](rec => linalg.Vectors.dense(rec.latitude, rec.longitude)).rdd), ...).

Comment: sry maybe some syntax errors in the lins but that is the idea. feel free to ask me if you have questions

Comment: This works, but it took so long time to be computed. I'm testing only with 50 users and 27k points. 

I tried with RDD and it calculates until 1k users and 300k points, but this is so small considering the high computing provided by Spark.

val rdd = stayDf.rawDF.select("objectID", "latitude", "longitude").rdd.map(row => {
    val lat = row.getDouble(1)
    val lng = row.getDouble(2)
    val ds = stayDf.rawDF.as[StayDataset]
    
    Seq(objectID, lat, lng)
}).groupBy(_.seq(0)).collect()
val dfs = rdd.map(r => groupStayPoints(r._1, r._2.map(row => Vectors.dense(...))

Comment: I think the distinct and the filter is the bottleneck of solution you proposed, because I already tried that filter with DataFrame and it took long time as your solution.

Comment: yes it is since collect invokes shuffle in spark. that's why i ask if you know all the objectId in the ds. if you don't have an objectId at first then you have to collect this to driver if you wanna treat each objectId differently which I think it's the case in your model optimization.